# reading inversed a dictionary python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have this code in python 3.7

```
dictionnaire = {'a':'url1', 'b':'url2', 'c': 'url3'}

for key, value in dictionnaire.items():
   print(key + ' ' + value)
```

the result is :

```
a url1
b url2
c url3
```

but i want this result

```
c url3
b url2
a url1
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the dictionary items to a list, in order to reverse it. You've two ways:

Using [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) function:

```
for k,v in reversed(list(dictionnaire.items())):
    print(k,v)
```

Using [`reverse`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) on the list object:

```
l = list(dictionnaire.items()).reverse()
for k,v in l:
    print(k,v)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by extracting keys from dictionary and reverse it.

```
keys = list(dictionnaire.keys())
```

Then use this list in reverse order to get the desired output.

```
for k in keys[::-1]:
    print(k, dictionnaire[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

## convert to list

`dic_list = list(dictionnaire.items())`

## reverse

`dic_list.reverse()`

## read

`for k, v in dic_list:
    print(k + ' ' + v)`